# .NET Desktop Runtime is required before installation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-5, setup-project

I've developed an application in .NET 5.0, also, I've a Setup Project to install this application in my clients.

My steps are:

1.- Publish the .NET 5.0 Application.
2.- Compile the Setup project.
3.- Install the setup.exe generated in "2" in the client.

But when I try to install the program in my client, windows says "This installation requires the 5.0.0(x64) version of .NET Desktop Runtime... So I've to download and install the SDK in every client.

My question is: There is some way to avoid this SDK installation? Can I embeed the .NET Desktop Runtime in the .NET 5.0 App or in the Setup Project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See [.NET application publishing overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), specifically [publishing a *self-contained* application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained). That way all necessary framework files will be included in your application, and you will not the framework to be installed. This will increase the disk requirement a bit if .Net 5 is already installed, since some files will be duplicated.

The alternative is to bundle the the .Net framework installer in your installation script. This will cause the setup-file to be quite a bit larger, unless the script downloads the framework on demand. But it may save some disk space in case there are multiple applications that use .Net 5.

Comment: I'm publishing a self-contained application but the Setup Project keeps asking me for the .NET SDK installation.

Comment: @RuSSe If you have a separate setup project then you likely have some declaration that instructs the installer to install the SDK. You should probably describe what setup-project you are using (i.e. WiX or Visual studio setup). I would look thru the setup project file for anything mentioning .Net. In my experience the UI is often limited for setup projects. But I would consider building a self-contained single file executable and skip the setup project.

Comment: Hi Jonas, it's fixed. In the Setup Project there is an option "Launch Conditions" to edit the conditions of the installer, but I can't delete .NET Core condition, the "Delete" button is disabled. So, I've to compile the project and edit the generated SetupProject.exe with Orca and in the table "_VsdLaunchCondition" delete the Row with condition "VSDNETCoreAvailable".

Comment: @RuSSe you might need to edit the setup project file by hand. In my experience, not all options are presented in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Go on projet Menu/ projetct properties / publish / require components / uncheck you frameWork .

[image]

[image]